# What does "s'en être" mean?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I'm confused by this sentence in *Le Petit Prince*:

> Le petit prince s’en fut revoir les roses.

If this said "Le petit prince s’en alla revoir les roses," I would interpret it as a passé simple conjugation of *s'en aller* and it would make sense to me. But what is *s'en être*?

Edit, Larousse says:

> 4. En langue courante ou familière s'emploie comme substitut du verbe aller aux temps composés ; en langue littéraire s'emploie au passé simple ou à l'imparfait du subjonctif au sens de s'en aller : J'ai déjà été chez lui hier. Il s'en fut dans la forêt.

I guess I understand, but I'm not really clear what the difference is, or if there is any. You can just arbitrarily substitute it for "aller" in the past tense? It says this is true for both "langue courante" as well as "lange littéraire"...

Comment: Je me demande si cet usage est à rapprocher du fait qu'en espagnol les formes du passé simple de *ir* (aller) et *ser* (être) sont rigoureusement identiques: *fui*, *fuiste*, *fue*, *fuimos*, *fueron*. De même pour *irse* (s'en aller): *me fui*, *te fuiste*, *se fue*, etc. C'est à se demander si on a raison d'associer l'infinitif *s'en être* aux formes en question, étant donné que seul le passé simple existe: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_%C3%AAtre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A place where you've gone is also a place where you've been, so the perfects of *aller* and *être* tend to overlap.

As your Larousse quote says, compound tenses of *être* are often substituted to those of *aller*: "J'ai été en vacances en France" instead of the more bookish "Je suis allé.e en vacances en France" or even "San Francisco ? J'ai déjà été" instead of "J'y suis déjà allé". Personally I never use *être allé* (but always *avoir été*) nor *s'en être allé* (but instead *être parti*) outside of formal writing but I don't think that's the case for most people, they just use both rather interchangeably.

A semantically similar shift is the one you've encountered in *Le Petit Prince* where the past simple "s'en fut" is used instead of "s'en alla". They're indeed equivalent and fully interchangeable in that context. Since the past simple is gone in everyday speech, literary narratives are the only place where you'll encounter that substitution nowadays.

Comment: Hmm bookish, really? In English "I was in France" and "I went to France" would both be completely equivalent in register and frequency of use - but the same is not true in French, and *être allé* sounds more formal or old-fashioned to you?